# Combining same name pdf files together from different folders

Tags: pdf, batch, combine

I have two folders, and both folders have around 20 thousands PDF files.

`Folder A  x.pdf, y.pdf, z.pdf`

`Folder B  x.pdf, y.pdf, z.pdf`

Now I'm in need of a software or a script to combine those folder which have the same name and place them in a new Folder C.

`Folder C   x.pdf` (which has combined from x.pdf from folder A and x.pdf from FolderB)

Comment: My main thought is knowing what you've tried, or were you just asking some one to write a script for you?

Comment: Bunch of products are offered in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2507766/1418463). The only thing you need is custom bash script which will call the software passing correct PDF files to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably write a script to iterate folder A, check if the file is also in folder B and then use pdftex, [texexec](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/TeXExec) or [itext](http://itextpdf.com/) to combine the two files.